# Making two different bones copy different axis on a target bone's rotation

Tags: bones, pose-mode

I am trying to rig a hand, ready to animate.

I have a hand bone that can rotate on y and z axes, and I have two other bones.I want the first one to follow the hand's bone y rotation and the second one the z rotation.

The hand bone is the green one and the red needs to follow the y axis of the hand. The blue needs to follow the z axis of the hand.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you talking about global or local axis? Are you sure your first bone can rotate on its Z axis?

Comment: i think i need it to be local because i will rotate the hand's bone (the green one) in normal orientation, and yes it can

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to copy rotation.

Under bone constraints, select `copy rotation`, and select the bone you want to take the rotation values from. You can also choose which axis to copy.

[image: Bone constraint -> Copy rot]

In your case, as you want the red bone to follow the hand bone's y axis, you would add a `copy rotation` on the red bone, and make the target the hand bone (green). Then you would uncheck the x and z boxes, so the red bone only looks at the hand bone's y rotation.

You would do the same with the blue bone. Add contraint, set target as hand bone, then make sure only z is selected.

If you are unsure of how to target the hand bone:

> Under `Target`, select `Armature`
>
> A new box will appear underneath, labelled `Bone`
>
> In the `Bone` box, select the hand bone.
>
> > You can also use the eyedropper icon. Select it, on the right of the box, and click on your Armiture, in the 3D (main editor) view.

Comment: i used copy rotation constraint, but the problem is the bone that needs to follow the y rotation (red bone) is working fine while rotating the hand in y axis between (90, -90) degrees but when i rotate the hand bone on the z axis while being between (90, -90)  degrees (but in the normal orientation, which i think is the reason why) the red bone starts to rotate itself in the y axis. and i'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: I see. It could help if you tell us exactly what you are trying to do. Are you rigging the character ready for animation? Because if you are, you can get away with just having the bones rigged normally, like this: https://imgur.com/a/Bnw8a1h (obviously wiith the fingers rigged too). You only really need control bones if you are using IK.

Comment: i have animations ready but it was done using a rig for a human arm but it doesn't make sense when using a robotic arm because  the robotic arm cant bend between the forearm and the hand like a normal arm so i needed a way to make it make sense so i modeled an object that allows rotation on the y and the z axis ( because  human hand can rotate vertically and a little bit horizontally) and put it between the forearm and the hand (as you can see in the pic with the question) and weight paint it and rigged it. now i need to rotate it with the motion i get from the hand's bone rotation. so that it

Comment: In situations like this, where a fix is needed for a small problem like this, a simpler solution may just be to tweak the animations. You say you have weight painted it? You _are_ using inverse kinematics?

Comment: i didn't bother to use ik since i only have two bones for the forearm and the hand

Comment: to put it clear my goal is not to worry about the joint between the forearm and the hand that i just talked about

Comment: How many animations do you have? Could it be easier to tweak them?

Comment: not too much but that's not the problem the problem is when i try to make more animations in the future i would need to animate the joint manually.

Answer (score 0):

First, a copy rotation constraint, as described by Malted_Wheaties in another answer, is sometimes an okay solution to this problem.  You've expressed that this stops working when you have rotations greater than 90 degrees; that's because at rotations greater than 90 degrees, Blender's Eulers angles start aliasing-- that is, there's more than one Euler triplet that can represent the orientation, and Blender doesn't end up giving the constraint the particular triplet that you wanted or expected.

There is a more complicated way to set this up that should be what you want, although it doesn't work via Euler angles, so it isn't really about Euler axes-- but usually, that's a good thing, something that better matches our intuitions about orientations.

I'll assume here that the heads of both "copy rotation" bones will be at the same location as their target, with the same parent and the same rest pose orientation.  This appears to be the case from your picture.  (If it's not the case, it can be worked around, but with greater complexity, and it's worth understanding the simpler version first.)

To "copy Z rotation", use a locked track constraint, targeting the *tail* of the other bone, on lock Z, track Y:

[image]

This will rotate the tracking bone about its Z axis to be able to point its tail in the same direction as the target's tail, as much as that is possible.

To copy Y rotation, we'll make a duplicate of the tracking bone to "store" its starting rotation, then we'll copy the *full* rotation of our target, and then finally we'll use a damped track constraint, targeting the tail of our duplicate, to get back to pointing our original direction:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Transformation` constraint to linearly map transforms and axes between target bone and owner bone.